# Loop through UL LI to get <a> text values

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to loop loop through a `UL LI` list to get my `<a>` text values?

Here's what I have tried:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href='#tab1'>tabOne</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>tabTwo</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>tabThree</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab4'>tabFour</a></li>
</ul>

function test() {
    var x = $("ul.tabs li").length
    alert(x)
    for (i = 0; i < x i++) { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is performing a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and your question is showing the same. What are you trying to accomplish in the end? Do you want an array of strings that are the names of each tab? What do you want to do with these values in the end?

Comment: I will manipulate the data later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops are a good go to method, but be careful mixing jQuery methods and properties with plain JavaScript methods and properties. They do not recognize the other's objects.

**Details commented in demo**

### Demo

```js
// This jQuery Object is like an array-like object
var lnx = $('.tabs a');

/* The .length property applies to any jQuery Object
|| Using let to define the increment variable is safe
*/
for (let i = 0; i < lnx.length; i++) {

  /* Since lnx is array-like, we can use bracket
  || notation to keep track of its current index
  || on each iteration.
  || The plain JavaScript property .textContent
  || works on lnx because the brackets and 
  || index number dereferrences the jQuery Object 
  || into a plain JavaScript Object
  */
  var txt = lnx[i].textContent;
  // Log results on each iteration
  console.log(txt + '\n');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href='#tab1'>tabOne</a></li>
  <li><a href='#tab2'>tabTwo</a></li>
  <li><a href='#tab3'>tabThree</a></li>
  <li><a href='#tab4'>tabFour</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) for this task:

```js
//for each "ul.tabs a" elements
$("ul.tabs a").each(function() {
  // $(this) represents to current iterated DOM element
  // $(this) is "a" element selector
  // If we were using a for(var i = 0;. . .) loop for arrayName[], $(this) would be arrayName[i]
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href='#tab1'>tabOne</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>tabTwo</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>tabThree</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab4'>tabFour</a></li>
</ul>
```